# Vue 2.0 on multipage app

Tags: vuejs2, multipage

I've just started out on Vue stumbled upon a question about architecture on multipage app, that I haven't been able to find an answer to anywhere.

I'm building a web application based on umbraco cms and only parts of the code on the various pages are vue code. In between, there's also a lot of normal cms output, that isn't rendered through vue, example:

```
          <div class="description">
            @Html.Raw(Model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="specifications product-onpage-link">
            <a href="#description" class="first-link" onclick="event.preventDefault(); productScroll('#description')">Se varebeskrivelsen</a> <a href="#specifications" onclick="event.preventDefault(); productScroll('#specifications')">Se tekniske specifikationer</a>
        </div>

        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Partials/Webshop/Products/Variant.cshtml", Model)

        @{
            var amountvalues = Model.StockInfo != null && Model.StockInfo.AmountValues != null ? Json.Encode(Model.StockInfo.AmountValues) : "";
        }

        <div id="add-to-basket" class="variant box rounded-borders">
            <add-to-basket amountplaceholder="@Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("Products: amount name")" id="@Model.ItemNo" orderminimum="@Model.StockInfo.OrderMinimum" amountvalues="@amountvalues" placeholder="@Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("Products: Add to basket button name")" nicename="@Model.StockInfo.Stock.NiceName" delivery="@Model.StockInfo.DeliveryTime" orderinterval="@(Model.StockInfo.OrderInterval == 0 ? 1 : Model.StockInfo.OrderInterval)" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

In this part, it's only the  element, that is rendered through vue.

My question is how to structure the vue code, when there could be many vue instances on the same page with a lot of regular cms rendered code in between.

My entry point for the vue code is

```
import productComponent from './product-overview';
import BuyButton from './shared/buy-button';

Vue.component('buy-button', BuyButton);

new Vue({
    el: '#add-to-basket'
});

new Vue({
    el: '.buytogether'
});

...
```

Here I actually generate a lot of vue instances. I'm thinking, there must be an easier way to this.

I can't handle all the vue code in one vue-app with a parent/child relationship between the components, because they are spread around the page with a lot of regular html in between, that is rendered by the server.

My fear is, that when I create several vue instances I'll loose performance.

Hope you have some good ideas, to how to structure the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the best way would be to have a single vue intance. Relationships can be handled through props if they're not too complex and with vuex if they are.

Although because you don't have a single page app, the state will not be shared between pages unless you use session, local storage or a database.